# C native android app crashes on Oreo and above due to signal(SIGALARM) call

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have created a C library using Android NDK and created an apk using this prebuild library. This apk calls the foo() function of the library. 
In this library I have two functions foo() and add(), foo() will call add() using signal(SIGALARM).
In C library, there is a memory allocation on the stack (simple declaring an array), if I allocate memory more than 9MB it will crash with sigsegv. 
You can also suggest an alternative of a signal in C on Unix platform as I want to call this add() function in the background only.

This apk runs fine till nougat. On Oreo and above the background process killed after a certain amount of memory allocation and I have found a workaround on java but I want to do the same on C what should I do please help. I have tried heap memory allocation which runs fine. But I want memory allocation on the stack only, when I allocate stack memory on foreground it runs fine. And how do I push notification using C?

Library code:

```
int foo(int a)
{

    signal(SIGALRM, add);
        alarm(5);
    return ++a;
}

void add(int signo)
{

    FILE *fptr =NULL;
    fptr = fopen("/sdcard/abc.txt","a+");
    if(fptr){
    fprintf(fptr,"%s", "start"); 
    fclose(fptr);
    }

    char arr[100000];

    //char *bytes = alloca(100000);


    fptr = fopen("/sdcard/abc.txt","a+");
    if(fptr){
    fprintf(fptr,"%s", "end"); 
    fclose(fptr);
    }

    sleep(2);

    alarm(2);
    //sleep(5);
    return;
}
```

---

apk code:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_sample_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{


    int calls = foo(5);

    while(1){

        break;
    }

    //pause();

        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "success");
}
```

Comment: Are you *really* calling `fopen()` in a signal handler?  You can only call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  Doing otherwise can cause undefined behavior.  `fopen()`, `fprintf()`, and `fclose()` are **not** async-signal-safe, and `alarm()` and `sleep()` may not be, depending on your platform.  You also need to check your platform's other restrictions on signal handlers about things like stack size limitations. Your problems here appear to be of the "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!"  "Well, don't do that." variety.

Comment: @andrew Yes, you are right, it was left out by mistake. Although we have removed fopen() but still facing the same issue. I think this issue is related to memory if I reduce the size of array it runs fine. And is there any alternative of signal in C. Actually we want to call a C function after particular time intervals on linux.

Comment: So what does your code look like after you remove the non-async-safe parts?

Comment: It looks like you are running into the system's stack size limit. Why would you need to allocate 9MB on the stack?  This might help: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art#Stack_Size

Comment: What do you even hope to accomplish by using a signal?  There's no reason to use that within a process, and there are many well documented means of IPC that make more sense to use externally.